# Bash bracing does not working with * on Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos

yesterday I watched a tutorial on  pluralsight and tried some of the examples. However, this one does not simply work on my Mac and I cannot find a reason why?

This is the simple command:

```
cp *.{pdf, docx} test/
```

This is the response (error) I got:

```
cp: *.{pdf,: No such file or directory

p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px Menlo; color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff} span.s1 {font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures}

cp: docx}: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra space present within the file-extensions, which shouldn't be present. It should have been,

```
cp *.{pdf,docx} test/
```

From `man bash` under `Brace expansion`

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain  unquoted  opening  and
>          closing  braces,  and  at  least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence
>          expression.  Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left  unchanged.
>          A { or , may be quoted with a backslash to prevent its being considered
>          part of a brace expression.  To avoid conflicts with  parameter  expan‐
>          sion, the string ${ is not considered eligible for brace expansion.
>
> This construct is typically used as shorthand when the common prefix of
>          the strings to be generated is longer than in the above example:
>
> mkdir /usr/local/src/bash/{old,new,dist,bugs}

Comment: It is exactly like this. You can see the example is 1:1 or I am wrong.